# Passing arguments in a selector in IPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I have a barButtonItem that calls an action which swaps two views in an animation block. I disable the `barButtonItem` at the beginning of the action method that it calls, and the I want to enable it when its finished, so that the user can't flip the view again before it has finished flipping.

It does this in a UIView animation block, so If I enable it at the ned of the method, it will be instant and that destroys the purpose because it gets enabled before the animation finishes.

In the method, I cast sender to a UIBarButtonItem, and I disable that. So I found `[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector()]`, but I need to pass my barButtonItem in the selector so the enableControl Method will enable that (this would be a lot easier if I could make an anonymous function..).

So how can I pass the barButton as an argument? I'd rather not have to make an ivar just for this.. Here's the code:

```
- (void)barBtnItemSwitchViews_Clicked:(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    barButton.enabled = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    if(!self.yellowVC.view.superview) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:innerView cache:YES];
        [yellowVC viewWillAppear:YES];
        [blueVC viewWillDisappear:YES];
        [blueVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.blueVC = nil;
        [innerView addSubview:yellowVC.view];
    } else if(!self.blueVC.view.superview) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:innerView cache:YES];
        [blueVC viewWillAppear:YES];
        [yellowVC viewWillDisappear:YES];
        [yellowVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.yellowVC = nil;
        [innerView addSubview:blueVC.view];
    }
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(enableControl:)]; // How do I pass barButton??
}

- (void)enableControl:(UIControl *)control {
    control.enabled = YES;
}
```

---

Here's what I changed it to, but the method isn't being called.. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)barBtnItemSwitchViews_Clicked:(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    barButton.enabled = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:barButton];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    if(!self.yellowVC.view.superview) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:innerView cache:YES];
        [yellowVC viewWillAppear:YES];
        [blueVC viewWillDisappear:YES];
        [blueVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.blueVC = nil;
        [innerView addSubview:yellowVC.view];
    } else if(!self.blueVC.view.superview) {
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:innerView cache:YES];
        [blueVC viewWillAppear:YES];
        [yellowVC viewWillDisappear:YES];
        [yellowVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        self.yellowVC = nil;
        [innerView addSubview:blueVC.view];
    }
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(flipViewAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)flipViewAnimationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)context;
    barButton.enabled = NO;
    NSLog(@"Disabled");
}
```

---

EDIT: I figured it out. I had to make the button the context, and then do `setAnimationDelegate:self`, and then `setAnimationDidEndSelector:@selector(myMethod:finished:context:)`, and then in the method cast context to `uibarbuttonitem` and re-enable it.

Comment: When you edit, don't remove the original question...

Comment: I put my original question back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From UIView's `setAnimationDidStopSelector:` docs:

> The selector should be of the form: `- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context`.

The third argument, `context`, is an object of your choice, set in `beginAnimations:context:`.  So it seems like what you're missing is to use `barButton` as the `context` argument, and then rewrite `enableControl` with a proper signature.  In that method, you take the third argument, `context`, and cast it from `void*` to a `UIBarButtonItem*`.

Comment: Thanks only thing you didn't mention is you need to do [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self] first.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think you can pass more than one argument to the selector by using @selector, however you could make your button a class variable and enable or disable it like that in the selector (instead of it being passed as an argument), to define a selector with multiple arguments you can use  NSInvocation, like so

```
NSInvocation *inv = [[NSInvocation alloc] init];
[inv setSelector:@selector(foo:bar:)];
[inv setArgument:123 atIndex:0];
[inv setArgument:456 atIndex:1];
```

But I dont think this will work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: First of all I did not say I need multiple arguments, I only wanted one. Secondly, I said I did not want to have to use an ivar (or class var)

Comment: What i meant is you cant pass aribitrary args into the selector